# Comparing and filling in excel data

Tags: excel

I have two excel spreadsheets. The first column of each is a column of serial numbers. Basically I need to take the first sheet, match the serial numbers from the other sheet (they are out of order and some are missing) and the fill in the unique data from the fist sheet into the appropriate columns of the second sheet. Does that make sense? I'm an excel noob, but I'm trying to learn! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use VLOOKUP in order to do that. In cell B2 on your second sheet, use the formula

```
=VLOOKUP($A2,Sheet1!A:B,2,FALSE)
```

From this, just add the column range as the second input between the serial number and the column you want to look up. Then repeat for each column.

Answer (score 1):

This picture shows the setup in the first sheet:

[image]

All of the data is hard coded.

This picture shows the setup in the second sheet.

[image]

As @timthebomb suggests, the formula in the second column (second row) is the following Vlookup:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!$A$2:$B$9,2,FALSE)
```